Can I create a site script that performs the steps below on a SP Site?
(Note: Referring to Modern SP Site below)
The steps:

Changes the look, specifically:

Theme
Header> Layout (to extended)
Header> Theme
Header> Background Img
Header> Site logo thumbnail
Header> Site logo
Header> Site logo alignment
Navigation> Horizontal &  Cascading


Copies a folder from another SP site
Copies pages from another SP site

I believe 2 and 3 can be achieved by calling a power automate function, but I don't know how to pass in the site name when calling the function. Is this possible with site scripts?
For 1, I tried but couldn't get it working for some of the steps listed.
